# QListWidget работает не так, как я планировал

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlistwidget

Мой код состоит из трех классов:

1. `RoundArt`, который создает изображение с закругленными углами;
2. `ListWidget`, который создает `QListWidget` с определенными характеристиками (важно - он не имеет полос прокрутки);
3. `MyWindow`, который создает окно приложения.

В `MyWindow` я создаю главный контейнер `box`, куда добавляю вертикальный контейнер `box_1` с полосой прокрутки.

В `box_1` располагается 4 виджета:

1. Надпись `label_1`;
2. Виджет `list_widget_1`, который является копией класса `ListWidget` и представляет из себя `QListWidget`;
3. Надпись `label_2`;
4. Виджет `list_widget_2`, который является копией класса `ListWidget` и представляет из себя `QListWidget`.

Виджеты `list_widget_1` и `list_widget_2` я заполняю изображениями с закругленными углами, копиями класса `RoundArt`.

Я предполагал, что `box_1`, имея вертикальную полосу прокрутки, позволит виджетам `list_widget_1` и `list_widget_2` занять необходимое пространство и растянуться по вертикали - но этого не произошло. Содержимое `ListWidget'ов` смещается вниз и перестало быть видимым:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне же необходимо, чтобы `list_widget_1` и `list_widget_2` занимали столько места, сколько необходимо для нормального отображения всех элементов, находящихся внутри них:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я показал на картинке, `list_widget_1` занял столько места, сколько ему нужно, а остальные виджеты (`label_2` и `list_widget_2`) отодвинулись вниз, и просмотреть их позволяет полоса прокрутки. При этом `list_widget_1` и `list_widget_2` должны сохранить способность располагать элементы по горизонтали, если есть свободное место. Пожалуйста, скажите, как мне это сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class RoundArt(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture: str, x: int, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoundArt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 10 

        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture: str):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)

        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)
        self.setSpacing(14)
        self.setContentsMargins(30, 30, 0, 30)
        self._rubberPos  = None
        self._rubberBand = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(140, 140))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setStyleSheet("border-style: hidden;")
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        box_1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(content_widget)
        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(scrollArea)

        list_widget_1 = ListWidget()
        list_widget_2 = ListWidget()

        label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label 1')
        box_1.addWidget(label_1)

        box_1.addWidget(list_widget_1)

        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label 2')
        box_1.addWidget(label_2)        

        box_1.addWidget(list_widget_2)

        for i in range(5):
            art = RoundArt('album', 150)
            list_widget_1.makeItem(art)

        for i in range(5):
            art = RoundArt('album', 150)
            list_widget_2.makeItem(art)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPD:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class RoundArt(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture: str, x: int, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoundArt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 10  
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture: str):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, 
            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
      
        self.setPixmap(target)
        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        
        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)
        self.setSpacing(10)
        #self.setContentsMargins(100, 100, 100, 100)             
        self._rubberPos  = None
        self._rubberBand = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)
        
    def updateHeight(self):
        self.setMaximumHeight(self.sizeHint().height())

    def getHeight(self, parent=None):
        height = 0
        if not parent:
            parent = self.rootIndex()
        for row in range(self.model().rowCount(parent)):
            child = self.model().index(row, 0, parent)
            height += 150 
        return height

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        hint.setHeight(self.getHeight())
        return hint

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return self.sizeHint()
        

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.dict = {} # словарь для хранения QListWidget'ов и количества изображений внутри них

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        #scrollArea.setStyleSheet("border-style: hidden;")
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.box_1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(content_widget)
        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(scrollArea)

        self.list_widget_1 = ListWidget()
        self.list_widget_2 = ListWidget()

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label 1')
        self.box_1.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.box_1.addWidget(self.list_widget_1, stretch = 1)
        
        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label 2')
        self.box_1.addWidget(label_2)        
        self.box_1.addWidget(self.list_widget_2, stretch=1)
        
        self.box_1.addStretch(100)

        a = 11 # любое число, позже программа будет получать его самостоятельно
        for i in range(a):
            art = RoundArt('album.png', 150)
            self.list_widget_1.makeItem(art)
            self.dict[self.list_widget_1] = a

        b = 5 # любое число, позже программа будет получать его самостоятельно
        for i in range(b):
            art = RoundArt('album.png', 150)
            self.list_widget_2.makeItem(art)
            self.dict[self.list_widget_2] = b

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        l = 150 # размер стороны изображения
        d = 10 # отступ между изображениями
        m = l + 2*d
        for widget in self.dict:
            n = self.dict[widget] # количество изображений
            k = (widget.width() - 4.5)//m
            if n % k  == 0:
                h = m*(n // k) + 4
            else:
                h = m*(n // k + 1) + 4
            widget.setMinimumHeight(h)

        self.update()
        super(MyWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я может чего и лишнего написал пока делал отладку,
поэкспериментируйте и если что найдете ненужное уберете
или подкорректируете.
Удачи.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class RoundArt(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture: str, x: int, num, *args, **kwargs):  # num для отладки 
        super(RoundArt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.num = num                                               # num для отладки 
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 10  
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture: str):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, 
            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
# +++ vvv  для отладки    
        path.addText(QtCore.QPoint(65, 90), 
                     QtGui.QFont("Times", 30, QtGui.QFont.Bold), 
                     str(self.num));
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0, 15));
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red);
        painter.drawPath(path)
# +++ ^^^        
        self.setPixmap(target)
        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        
        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)
        self.setSpacing(14)
        self.setContentsMargins(30, 30, 0, 30)             
        self._rubberPos  = None
        self._rubberBand = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))                         # ??? 140, 140
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def updateHeight(self):
        self.setMaximumHeight(self.sizeHint().height())

    def getHeight(self, parent=None):
        height = 0
        if not parent:
            parent = self.rootIndex()
        for row in range(self.model().rowCount(parent)):
            child = self.model().index(row, 0, parent)
            height += 150 
        return height

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        hint.setHeight(self.getHeight())
        return hint

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return self.sizeHint()    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setStyleSheet("border-style: hidden;")
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.box_1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(content_widget)  # self.
        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(scrollArea)

        self.list_widget_1 = ListWidget()                   # self.
        self.list_widget_2 = ListWidget()

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label 1')           # self.
        self.box_1.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.box_1.addWidget(self.list_widget_1, stretch=1)  # stretch=1
        
        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label 2')
        self.box_1.addWidget(label_2)        
        self.box_1.addWidget(self.list_widget_2, stretch=1)  # , stretch=1 
        
        self.box_1.addStretch(1)                             # +

        for i in range(5):
#            art = RoundArt('album', 150)
            art = RoundArt('_ph_.png', 150, i)                # + i для отладки
            self.list_widget_1.makeItem(art)

        for i in range(5):
            art = RoundArt('150_150.png', 150, i)             # + i для отладки
            self.list_widget_2.makeItem(art)  
            
    def resizeEvent(self, event):  
        if self.width() < 414:
            self.list_widget_1.setMinimumHeight(960)
            self.list_widget_2.setMinimumHeight(960)
        elif 414 <= self.width() < 592:
            self.list_widget_1.setMinimumHeight(576)
            self.list_widget_2.setMinimumHeight(576)            
        elif 592 <= self.width() < 948:
            self.list_widget_1.setMinimumHeight(384)
            self.list_widget_2.setMinimumHeight(384)            
        else:
            self.list_widget_1.setMinimumHeight(192) 
            self.list_widget_2.setMinimumHeight(192)

        self.update()
        super(MyWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

> ... Я изменил ваш код и добавил его в свой вопрос. Почему-то пока не могу найти в нем подвох, т.к. кажется, что все работает. Это странно, поэтому я решил снова обратиться к вам. Не могли бы вы проверить этот код на ошибки, если будет время?

Я проверил ваш пример, который вы опубликовали в обновлении, на нескольких вариантах (логику расчета я не проверял). Единственное что я обнаружил, что при загрузке приложения, окно неправильно отображается, но изменив размер окна отображается правильно.

Предлагаю поправить это так:

```
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    
    print(window.size())                     # +++  для отладки
    window.resize(300, 335)                  # +++  после show() !!!
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. Сейчас я разбирал ваш код. Он работает именно так, как мне было нужно, но если число закругленных изображений станет отличным от пяти, все сломается. Понимаю причину этого и то, что снова забыл указать одну важную деталь - число закругленных изображений может быть любым, и предсказать это число я не могу. Прошу прощения за свою ошибку. Я пытался подумать над решением этой проблемы, но в голову приходил только один способ - заранее задать высоты `QtWidgets`'а для каждого числа закругленных изображений в нем. Не умещаю мысли в этом комментарии, поэтому вынужден написать еще один

Comment: Я понимаю, что такой вариант нежизнеспособен, поэтому хотел спросить, может, вы знаете способ решения моей проблемы? Если так, очень хотел бы его увидеть. Могу оформить проблему в новом вопросе, если это нужно

Comment: @MAXIM045 я надеялся, что вы сами найдете эту закономерность между шириной  (`self.width()` ) и высотой (`self.list_widget.setMinimumHeight()`).  Честно скажу вам, что мне, пока, не хочется этим заниматься. Может когда станет совсем скучно. Скажу вам, что ваше идея имеет право на жизнь и может оказаться самым простым решением. Предлагаю вам для начала реализовать ее, а дальше посмотрим.

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую вывести формулу для высоты, но совсем не уверен, что получится

Comment: Попробовал решить проблему. Я изменил ваш код и добавил его в свой вопрос. Почему-то пока не могу найти в нем подвох, т.к. кажется, что все работает. Это странно, поэтому я решил снова обратиться к вам. Не могли бы вы проверить этот код на ошибки, если будет время? Прошу прощения за свою  настойчивость

Comment: @MAXIM045 я проверю ваш пример чуть позже.

Comment: @MAXIM045 смотрите обновление к ответу.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое :) Хотел спросить, является ли неправильное отображение окна при загрузке багом PyQt?